# When to modify Poky vs creating a new distro

Tags: yocto

Even though I *can* technically add .bbappend files to a custom layer that change the behavior of the .bb files in meta-poky, I'm not certain that this is good practice?

For example, I want to use networkd to to configure eth0 to use DHCP, and bridge all remaining network interfaces (eth* and wlan*) together with a static IP. This is really easy to do by adding a systemd_%.bbappend that installs additional networkd unit files. However, I'd be modifying Poky for all boards using systemd. I could make the modification machine specific, but then I'd have to do it for each new custom board.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always create your own distro.  Poky can and will change between releases because it is primarily designed to be a testbed for QA.

Comment: One thing that confuses me is that looking at the meta-boot2qt and meta-angstrom layers, they use bbappends yet those appends would kick in simply by having the layer included even if I had set DISTRO to poky. These layers don't seem to bother with variable, function, and file overrides for their distros. Is this accepted practice, and it is up to the user to manage having only one distro layer enabled at a time?

Comment: The part that confuses me is that both these layers, in effect, modify Poky (and all other distros) as well as create their own distro. I just want to make sure I am doing things in a way that other Yocto developers would recognize as normal conventions.

Comment: To follow-up, I did receive clarification from the #yocto channel on Freenode and these distro layers *should* make use of the overrides such that when their layer is enable, but the distro is not selected, they do not modify the build output of other distros.

Comment: I have also learned that this requirement is relatively new, and therefore, many distro layers do not yet comply with this rule. So be careful when looking at existing layers as an example, if you wish your new work to be compliant.

Answer (score 2):

Also do try to avoid bbappends if at all possible. They make it more difficult to create a picture of the whole recipe in your head, particularly if you start by looking at the recipe itself, and don't know that there are also bbappends in other layers that modify it.

Comment: Good point. I am examining alot of recipe files at the moment, and locating and mentally merging all the bbappends is a pain.